# Basic proof, but just need confirmation that it's ok

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

I am reading Tao's Analysis 1. 
I am asked to prove that $n \times m = 0 \Leftrightarrow n=0 \;\text{or}\; m=0$

Please keep in mind that multiplicative inverse has not been defined in my text so I don't want to use it! If no one is familiar with the definition of multiplication used in this text then I will post it!.

We must show that  $n \times m = 0$ implies $n = 0$ or $m = 0$ AND that $n = 0$ or $m = 0$ implies that $n \times m = 0$.

We prove the second implication first;
suppose that $n = 0$ then $0 \times m = 0$ by definition of multiplication.
now suppose that $m = 0$ then $n \times 0 = 0 \times m = 0$, again by the def of multiplication.

We now prove the first implication;
suppose that $n \times m = 0$, then either $n = 0$ or $n$ is not equal to 0.
suppose that $n = 0$ then $0 \times m = 0$ as required.
now suppose that n is not equal to 0. 
$n \times m = m \times n = 0$

By the definition of multiplication $0 \times n = 0$, as required,

This last part is quite fishy I think!

EDIT

$n$ and $m$ are natural numbers.

DEFINITION OF MULTIPLICATION!

Let $m$ be a natural number. To multiply zero to $m$, we define $0 \times m := 0$. Now suppose inductively..... the rest is not relevant to this proof.

Comment: What _is_ your definition of multiplication? What does $n$ and $m$ range over?

Comment: $n\times m= 0=m+(-m)\Rightarrow$

$(n+1)\times m=m$. 

If $m=0$, we are done. If not, then $(n+1)=1$. For the other part, $0\times m=(1-1)\times m=m-m=0$

Comment: This is very hard to answer unless we know precisely which properties / axioms of real number (if you talk about real numbers at all) have been defined and can be used.

Comment: I shall edit now! sorry guys!

Comment: swapnil Tripathi, i don't quite follow, but everything you have used is defined in tao's analysis. could you elaborate slightly please.